# Retaining workflow history when upgrading to SharePoint 2013

Tags: workflow, workflow-history

I'm currently in the process of upgrading our SharePoint 2010 environment to Sharepoint 2013 on some test servers. After the upgrade I noticed a lot of our workflow history has disappeared. SharePoint keeps the tasks however the history doesn't seem to come across. Here is a before and after of the same library in both 2010 and 2013:

[image: sharepoint 2010]

[image: sharepoint 2013]

Does anybody know why the workflow history is being cleared and is there any way to retain it after the upgrade?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :( It is not a deal breaker for the upgrade since the history is retained in a separate list, but it's a huge pain to set it up so you can accurately see the workflow events.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the dates I see in your screenshot, it is probably the workflow history cleanup job that removes the workflow history associations after 60 days.  I wonder if this job was disabled on your 2010 environment and not on 2013.

See here for more details:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662522(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer Steve, if it was the workflow history job though I wouldn't be able to click 'Approved' beside the document to view the tasks (right?). That workflow column gets cleared out when the association is deleted. For some reason I'm still able to view the tasks associated with the workflow, just not the detailed history.

Comment: I'm not sure.  Do you have any items that are within the past 60 days that also don't have workflow history?

Comment: We do, I just took a look and items from June 18 are missing their workflow history... The tasks are there, it's just the history is gone.